# PHP: How to limit processor usgae (Use only one core of CPU for example) or %10 Percent?

Tags: php, process

In PHP I can set memory LIMIT using ini settings `ini_set("memory_limit","24M");` however, I want to dedicate only one core of the processor for all PHP programs on my server.

Currently, I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 running on Dell Workstation (8GB Ram, and Core i7 Processor). I solved this issue by using VMWare and dedicating only one core and 2GB for that virtual server, however, I am looking for configuration per module or per folder to assign different processor limit, if possible.

Comment: Please guys, if this question not good here, move it to another site such as Server Fault if appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the quota system to limit by user.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384148%28WS.10%29.aspx

If you are running PHP as a user, this will work

> If you want to limit processes running under the account with SID
>   S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415 to use
>   only 10% of the CPU bandwidth, you would do the following; Open an
>   administrator command prompt.
>
> Type reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\Quota
>   System\S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415.
>
> Open the Registry Editor and locate the sub key you created in the
>   previous step.
>
> Under this key, create a new REG_DWORD value CpuRateLimit and set its
>   value to 10.
>
> This will limit all the processes running under that account SID to
>   use only 10% of the CPU.

Comment: wow great, this will be an alternative, however, I am looking for native php hacks to do this.

Comment: I know you are looking for php code to do this, but you can also automate these tasks using c# code.

Comment: PHP: `shell_exec('reg add....');` OR `win32std library` + `reg_open_key();` as shown here: http://phpmaster.com/access-the-windows-registry-from-php/ | Searched google "php regedit"